# warning :data truncated for column 'username' at row 1 when using database mysql with django

Tags: mysql, database, django, warnings, mysql-python

I am getting the above mentioned warning

> > > data truncated for column 'username' at row 1

I am getting this for my model **"suserprofile" with "username" as my first listed field** in the model

I checked max_length option which is not the problem for me,
if I change the order of my fields in the my model(changed "email_id" field to the first in list of the model),then I am getting the warning replacing 'username' with whatever field I mentioned first(in this case email_id) in the model.

I am not getting this warning when running syncdb but getting warning only when I am trying to save a new object in my model("suserprofile") in my views.py file using django by actually running the local browser.
I am not understanding why is it happenning

edit:

**my model:**

```
class SUserProfile(models.Model):
    email_id            = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    username      = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)  
    first_name          = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name           = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**my view**

```
from django.allauth.models import SocialAccount
def profileview(request):
    user=request.user   
    if user.is_authenticated:
        a=SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=user)   
        try:    
            f=a.get(provider='facebook')
        except:
            f=None
    if f:
        fusername=f.get_provider_account    
        fdata=f.extra_data 
        ffirst_name=fdata['first_name']     
        flast_name=fdata['last_name']
        femail=fdata.get('email')
        try: 
            old_user=SUserProfile.objects.get(email_id=femail)
        except:
            new_user=SUserProfile( 
            username=fusername,
            email_id=femail,
            first_name=ffirst_name,
            last_name=flast_name,)
            new_user.save()
```

**warning details I'm getting when running the browser:**

```
 Exception Type:    Warning

 Exception Value:   Data truncated for column 'email_id' at row 1

 Exception Location:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _warning_check, line 92

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view

       return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

...

▶ Local vars
/home/varun/webops/mysite/allauth/account/views.py in profileview

       new_user.save()

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save

self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base

result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in _insert

       return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in insert_query

    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

...

 ▶ Local vars
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql

    cursor.execute(sql, params)

...

 ▶ Local vars
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py in execute

    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute

    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in execute

    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()

...

▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py in _warning_check

     warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)

...

▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Old question, but small reminder: When changing the models in Django ALWAYS make sure that you execute `makemigrations` and `migrate`! Otherwise, your database will still have the old schema and you will wonder, why it doesn't work. I'm speaking from experience here :D

Answer (score 8):

check the column format and length.
i got same error when inserting string data with 20 char in varchar column with 10 in length.

Answer (score 4):

syncDB will not overwrite existing table/column definitions. So if you've already checked to make sure the lengths in your file are correct, you may want to check that you have remade your tables - you need to drop and recreate them in order for the updated column definitions to be put in place (I've made this error a couple of times myself)